# How to deal with missing values when creating a new variable with an equation across columns

Tags: r, na

I have a data frame:

```
a <- c(0, 0, 1, 3, NA, 0, 0, NA)
b <- c(NA, 0, 1, 3, 3, NA, 6, 4)
c <- c(0, NA, 1, 1, 5, 0, NA, 0)
d <- c(4, 0, 0, 2, 3, NA, 1, 4)
e <- c(NA, NA, 0, 0, 6, 1, 1, 0)
f <- c(0, NA, 0, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f)
df

   a  b  c  d  e  f
1  0 NA  0  4 NA  0
2  0  0 NA  0 NA NA
3  1  1  1  0  0  0
4  3  3  1  2  0  0
5 NA  3  5  3  6  3
6  0 NA  0 NA  1  5
7  0  6 NA  1  1  1
8 NA  4  0  4  0  4
```

I want to create new variables as follows:

```
df %>%
  mutate(new_var1 = a + (b/7),
         new_var2 = c + (d/7),
         new_var3 = e + (f/7))
```

Within pairs, if the value in column a, c, or e is not NA, but the value in column b, d, or f is NA, then I would like R to return the value in a, c, or e.

If the value in column a, c, or e is NA, but the value in column b, d, or f is not, then I would like R to return b/7, d/7, or f/7.

Since I want to do this across multiple pairs of columns in the data frame, it would also be helpful to know a more efficient way to iterate through.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what if when both a and b are NA? what do you want to return?

Comment: If both values are NA I'd like to return NA

Comment: Check the provided solution below

Answer (score 1):

In base R:

```
reshape(df, matrix(seq(ncol(df)),2), dir='long')|>
   transform(new_var = ifelse(is.na(a), b/7,
                       ifelse(is.na(b), a, a+(b/7))))|>
   reshape(dir='wide', drop = c('a','b'), sep='')

    id  new_var1  new_var2  new_var3
1.1  1 0.0000000 0.5714286 0.0000000
2.1  2 0.0000000 0.0000000        NA
3.1  3 1.1428571 1.0000000 0.0000000
4.1  4 3.4285714 1.2857143 0.0000000
5.1  5 0.4285714 5.4285714 6.4285714
6.1  6 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.7142857
7.1  7 0.8571429 0.1428571 1.1428571
8.1  8 0.5714286 0.5714286 0.5714286
```

Answer (score 0):

You show a logic that considers the first and adjacent column to the right, and then moves two to the right. You could set up a function `f` with the replacement instructions, for efficiency avoiding `ifelse` in favor of subsetting.

```
f <- \(x) {
  y <- x + 1
  s0 <- !is.na(df[, x]) & !is.na(df[, y])
  s1 <- !is.na(df[, x]) & is.na(df[, y])
  s2 <- is.na(df[, x]) & !is.na(df[, y])
  r <- rep.int(NA_real_, nrow(df))
  r[s0] <- df[s0, x] + df[s0, y]/7
  r[s1] <- df[s1, x]
  r[s2] <- df[s2, y]/7
  r
}
```

Then just use the `f`unction in an `sapply` with a `seq`uence [1, 3, 5, ..., ncol(df) - 1].

```
r <- sapply(seq.int(1, ncol(df) - 1, 2), f) |> 
  `colnames<-`(paste0('nv', seq_len(ncol(df)/2)))
r
#              nv1       nv2       nv3
# # [1,] 0.0000000 0.5714286 0.0000000
# # [2,] 0.0000000 0.0000000        NA
# # [3,] 1.1428571 1.0000000 0.0000000
# # [4,] 3.4285714 1.2857143 0.0000000
# # [5,] 0.4285714 5.4285714 6.4285714
# # [6,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.7142857
# # [7,] 0.8571429 0.1428571 1.1428571
# # [8,] 0.5714286 0.5714286 0.5714286
```

Finally `cbind` the result to your data frame.

```
cbind(df, r)
```

This appears to be five times faster than using `reshape/ifelse`.

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(0, 0, 1, 3, NA, 0, 0, NA), b = c(NA, 0, 
1, 3, 3, NA, 6, 4), c = c(0, NA, 1, 1, 5, 0, NA, 0), d = c(4, 
0, 0, 2, 3, NA, 1, 4), e = c(NA, NA, 0, 0, 6, 1, 1, 0), f = c(0, 
NA, 0, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```